# Geometry problem involving perpendiculars dropped from an interior point in a triangle to its altitudes

Tags: geometry

Consider the following question :-

> In a triangle $ABC$, with $AB = 6$, $BC = 3$ and $CA = 5$, $P$ is an interior point. From $P$, perpendiculars $PA'$, $PB'$ and $PC'$ are drawn to altitudes $AD$, $BE$ and $CF$ such that $AA' = BB' = CC'$. Find the length of $AA'$ (which is same as that of $BB'$ and $CC'$), and also find the distances of $P$ from $A$, $B$ and $C$.

I tried solving this question using coordinate geometry by assuming $A$ as origin, assuming $AA' = BB' = CC' = x$, finding the coordinates of the various points, finding the line equations of $PA'$, $PB'$ and $PC'$, and then using the condition that these are concurrent to solve for $x$, but the equations were getting too complicated.

I am sure there is a better way using Euclidean geometry, without using coordinate geometry. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost a complete answer now.

$H$ is the orthocenter.

[image]

Animated version of this Geogebra image [here](https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/vbmwedar) : you can drag point $P$.

I have found by trial and error that in order it fulfills condition

$AA'=BB'=CC',\tag{*}$

$P$ should have coordinates $(x_0,y_0)\approx(2.333, 0.356)$ (wrt to the frame below where $A$ is placed at the origin).

Here is the principle of a solution.

Take the midpoint $G$ of $BC$ as origin, and $x$ axis along $AB$.

In this way, we have $A=(-3,0)$ and $B=(3,0)$.

Let $P=(x_0,y_0)$ and $r:=AA'=BB'=CC'$.

It is easy, using Heron's formula, to obtain

$$CF=\frac23 \sqrt{14}$$

which implies :

$$r=\frac23 \sqrt{14}-y_0 \tag{1}$$

As angles $\angle ADB$ and $\angle AEB$ are right angles, $D$ and $E$ belong to the circle $(C)$ centered in the origin $G$ with radius $3$. Let the coordinates of these points be denoted :

$$D=(3\cos 2\alpha, 3\sin 2\alpha) \ \text{and} \ E=(3\cos 2\beta, 3\sin 2\beta)$$

Therefore, by inscribed angle formula in circle $(C)$:

$$\angle DAB = \alpha \ \text{and} \ \angle EBA = \beta$$

Therefore

$$A'=(-3+r \cos \alpha, r \sin \alpha)  \ \text{and} \ B'=(3+r \cos \beta, r \sin \beta)$$

($r$ has been defined upwards).

As $PA' \perp AA'$ and $PB' \perp BB'$ we can set the following dot products to $0$ :

$$\begin{cases}\binom{-3+r \cos \alpha-x_0}{r \sin \alpha-y_0} \ . \ \binom{\cos \alpha}{\sin \alpha}&=&0\\
\binom{3+r \cos \beta-x_0}{r \sin \beta-y_0} \ . \ \binom{\cos \beta}{\sin \beta}&=&0  \end{cases}\tag{2}$$

Plugging the value of $r$ issued from (1) into equations (2) we get a system of 2 *linear* equations with 2 unknowns $x_0,y_0$ (indeed $\alpha$ and $\beta$ aren't unknowns : I leave it the computations of their values to you... but see remark below) and it is (virtually !) finished.

Is your own solution along the same lines ?

Remark : I have computed $AF=\frac{14}{3}$,  $FB=\frac{4}{3}$,$HF=\frac{65}{6 \sqrt{14}}$. Using these values, one can get $\tan \alpha$ and  $\tan \beta$, then find $\alpha$ and   $\beta$

Comment: I tried again by coordinate geometry, it took a lot of calculation, but I got AA' = BB' = CC' = (2/7)*√56 , which is matching with what your diagram says. But a Euclidean Geometry solution would still be preferred.

Comment: Could you please tell me how you found the location of point P?

Comment: See the (almost complete) solution I propose, still (alas...) by analytic geometry.

Comment: I have computed $AF=\frac{14}{3}$,  $FB=\frac{4}{3}$,$HF=\frac{65}{6 \sqrt{14}}$. Using these values, one can get $\tan \alpha$ and  $\tan \beta$, then find $\alpha$ and   $\beta$

Comment: Thank you! Yes, my solution was on somewhat similar lines. I have briefly explained it in my question. I found the line equations of PA', PB' and PC' and used the condition for concurrency.

Comment: Thanks for your thanks and comment. What I haven't said is that the fact that $(x_0,y_0)$ is a solution of a linear system warrants a unique solution (of course if the main determinant is non-zero).